# How to synchronize child threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently creating an algorithm for solving the 0-1 knapsack problem using dynamic programming with multiple threads. My approach is to solve the `n` by `capacity` dynamic programming table by dividing it into 4 `n` by `capacity / 4` parts which will be solved by 4 threads. Because of the knapsack having a dependency on the upper row, all the 4 threads need to be solving the same row every time. They must wait for all the threads to finish their parts on the current row before proceeding to the next row.

Here is my code:

```
int knapsackParallel(char *values, char *weights, int N, int capacity) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    arguments[j].cpuNum = j;

    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, solveRow, (void *) &arguments[j]);

    pthread_setaffinity_np(tid[j], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpusets[j]);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
  }
}
```

Here is the code of each thread that needs synchronization:

```
void *solveRow(void *arguments) {
  int cpuNum = ((args *) arguments)->cpuNum;
  int initial = ((args *) arguments)->cpuNum * (capacity / p);
  int limit = cpuNum == p - 1 ? capacity + 1 : initial + (capacity / p);

  for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = initial; j < limit; j++) {
      // for the top and left edges, initialize to 0
      if (i == 0 || j == 0)
        table[i][j] = 0;
      // find the max between putting the value in the knapsack or not
      else if (weights[i] <= j)
        table[i][j] = fmax(values[i] + table[i - 1][j - weights[i]], table[i - 1][j]);
      // copy the value in the top of the cell
      else
        table[i][j] = table[i - 1][j];
    }

    // insert code here to wait for all the threads to finish their current iteration
    // before proceeding to the next iteration
  }
```

What I have tried so far:

Using multiple semaphores:

```
sem_post(&locks[cpuNum]);
sem_post(&locks[cpuNum]);
sem_post(&locks[cpuNum]);

for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
  if (j == cpuNum) continue;
  sem_wait(&locks[j]);
}
printf("thread %d done\n", cpuNum);
```

Using `pthread_cond_wait`:

```
locks[cpuNum] = 1;

if (locks[0] && locks[1] && locks[2] && locks[3]) {
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&full);
}
else {
  pthread_cond_wait(&full, &lock);
}
locks[cpuNum] = 0;
```

Using `futex`:

```
locks[cpuNum] = 1;

futex_wait(&locks[0], 0);
futex_wait(&locks[1], 0);
futex_wait(&locks[2], 0);
futex_wait(&locks[3], 0);

locks[cpuNum] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for posix barriers: [`pthread_barrier_init`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html), [`pthread_barrier_wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html).

A barrier can solve some of the same problems as `pthread_join`, but without actually having threads terminate and start again.

A barrier is initialized with a certain count. When that many threads call the wait operation, the barrier activates, and they are all unblocked. One of the threads receives a distinct return value, telling it it is the "serial thread": it can then perform some special job.

Thus each `barrier_wait` point in the program's logic is a rendezvous where all threads meet, which guarantees that whatever activity they were cooperating on is in a completed state.  If their activity needs to be integrated together (e.g. partial results combined into a full result), the serial thread can do that, followed by another barrier where all the threads rendezvous again, to kick off another bout of parallel work.

Answer (score 1):

[Another answer has brought barriers to my attention. Using a barrier greatly reduces the code needed at no cost. Best to use that.]

If you had a var with the active row number, the threads could simply wait until that's updated.

```c
#define NUM_WORKERS 4

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int active_row_num      = 0;
static int outstanding_threads = NUM_WORKERS;

static void done_row( int row_num ) {
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

   if ( --outstanding_threads == 0 ) {
      ++active_row_num;
      outstanding_threads = NUM_WORKERS;
      pthread_cond_broadcast( &cond );
   }

   ++row_num;
   while ( row_num != active_row_num )
      pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}

static void *worker( void *arg ) {
   for ( int row_num=0; row_num<...; ++row_num ) {
      ...

      done_row( row_num );
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing well by calling [pthread_join](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) for the threads you aim to synchronize, because that assures that your main thread will wait until the other threads are done:

[image]

The problem seems to be that you are not calling [pthread_exit](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) in the threads that are to be synchronized:

[image]

Comment: My problem is synchronizing each thread so that each thread is solving the same row at a given time (avoid scenarios like thread 2 is already solving row 2 while thread 1 is still on row 1). The program only creates 4 threads so the pthread_exit does not really affect since it is in the end of the threads.

Comment: @keijeizei So, you want four threads to work on row1. When completed, you need four threads to work on row2. You want to avoid the scenario of a thread already starting to work on row2 while another thread is still working on row1. This means that you 1. loop your rows in the main thread 2. in each step, you start by creating 4 threads to work on current row and 3 upon the end of each step, you pthread_join the 4 threads. So, you guarantee that each row will be fully processed before the next row's processing starts.